# Unclosed bracket on Aggregate

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting the error "Unable to execute: there is an unclosed bracket in the statement:" on the following MongoDB query:

```
db.moicaTickets.aggregate([

    { $match : 
        { asunto:{$exists:true},
          asunto: {$ne:null},
          tiempos:{$exists:true}, 
          tiempos: {$ne:null},
          problemas:{$exists:true},
          creado:{$exists:true}, 
          estado_actual: {$exists: true},
          "estado_actual.estado": {$eq: 'Cerrado'},
          asuntoCierre: {$ne:'Cierre Automatico'},
          "creado.lastEvent_tc": { $gt: start, $lt: end } }},
    { $project: 
        {   pFecha: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", date: "$creado.lastEvent_tc", timezone: "-03:00" } }, 
            asunto: 1, 
            tiempos: 1, 
            nroTkt: 1,
            estado_actual: 1,
            fechaCierre: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", date: "$cerrado.lastEvent_tc", timezone: "-03:00" }},
            losProblemas: { $arrayElemAt: ["$problemas",0]},
            primera:{
                          $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$tipoCreado", 'Manual' ] } , $arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",0] , $arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",1] ]
                   }

        },
        { $addFields: { "lacola":{ "$toObjectId": "$primera.cola" }}},
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: "moicaTicketsColas",
         localField: "lacola",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "nombreCola"
         }}

         ]).forEach(function(doc){
         try {
         print(doc.nroTkt+";"+doc.nombreCola[0].arbol+";"+doc.estado_actual.estado+";"+doc.pFecha+";"+doc.fechaCierre+";"+doc.asunto.titulo+";"+doc.losProblemas.nombre);
         } catch (err) {
          print(doc.nroTkt+";"+doc.nombreCola[0].arbol+";"+doc.estado_actual.estado+";"+doc.pFecha+";"+doc.fechaCierre+";"+doc.asunto.titulo+";N/A");
         }
     })
```

This happened when I added the following lines:

```
primera:{
                      $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$tipoCreado", 'Manual' ] } , $arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",0] , $arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",1] ]
               }
```

And

```
asuntoCierre: {$ne:'Cierre Automatico'},
```

Is there something wrong with my $cond?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have to use curly braces for second and 3rd expression inside the `$cond` operator. Something like `primera:{
                      $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$tipoCreado", 'Manual' ] } ,{ $arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",0]} , {$arrayElemAt: ["$tiempos",1] ]}
               }`

Comment: Thnaks! I did the changes but I still get the error. Is that expression right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "asunto": { "$exists": true },
      "asunto": { "$ne": null },
      "tiempos": { "$exists": true },
      "tiempos": { "$ne": null },
      "problemas": { "$exists": true },
      "creado": { "$exists": true },
      "estado_actual": { "$exists": true },
      "estado_actual.estado": { "$eq": "Cerrado" },
      "asuntoCierre": { "$ne": "Cierre Automatico" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "pFecha": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
          "date": "$creado.lastEvent_tc",
          "timezone": "-03:00"
        }
      },
      "asunto": 1,
      "tiempos": 1,
      "nroTkt": 1,
      "estado_actual": 1,
      "fechaCierre": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
          "date": "$cerrado.lastEvent_tc",
          "timezone": "-03:00"
        }
      },
      "losProblemas": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$problemas", 0] },
      "primera": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": ["$tipoCreado", "Manual"] },
          { "$arrayElemAt": ["$tiempos", 0] },
          { "$arrayElemAt": ["$tiempos", 1] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$addFields": { "lacola": { "$toObjectId": "$primera.cola" } } },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "moicaTicketsColas",
      "localField": "lacola",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "nombreCola"
    }
  }
]
```